# Hadoop MultipleOutputs throws “cannot find symbol”

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop 0.21.0. I want to output to two different files, so I'm trying to get MultipleOutputs working. Here is my Reduce :

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer < Text, Text > {
  private MultipleOutputs mos;
  public void configure(JobConf conf) {
    mos = new MultipleOutputs(conf);
  }
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator < Text > values, OutputCollector < Text, Text > output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    mos.getCollector("A", reporter).collect(key, new Text("Hello"));
    mos.getCollector("B", reporter).collect(key, new Text("Bye"));
    mos.getCollector("C", reporter).collect(key, new Text("Chau"));
  }
  public void close() throws IOException {
    mos.close();
  }
}
```

But when I try to compile this I get these errors:

```
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        private MultipleOutputs mos;
                ^
  symbol:   class MultipleOutputs
  location: class Reduce

Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
            mos = new MultipleOutputs(conf);
                      ^
  symbol:   class MultipleOutputs
  location: class Reduce
```

Though I have added this: `import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*`;
at the beginning of the code.

Could anyone please tell me why I get these errors?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot find symbol` error tends to be associated with having multiple classes in your classpath that confuse the compiler at compile time when you know you have imported the class library.

Here are others who experienced similar problems:
[cannot find symbol](http://www.coderanch.com/t/402221/java/java/Compiler-Error-find-symbol)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.*; and it starded working with some warnings! It was strange since I already added import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;